# Set visibility when printing report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that I would like to display with some data hidden on default, toggled by another textbox.  No problem.  When you export that report to PDF, you still have access to the data by clicking the plus sign next to the textbox.  However, if you print or export to PDF & Word, the hidden data is gone.

Is there a way to hook into the act of printing or exporting programmatically and expanding all those items so they are visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

through the variable **RenderFormat.IsInteractive**, you can check wether the report is interactive, like PDF. You can use this in you visibility check.

Check out this [Link](http://kkryczka.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/ssrs-2008-how-to-hide-report%E2%80%99s-elements-on-export/) 
 for more information.